# Отладчик для обратной разработки Mach-O 64-bit на i686 GNU/Linux

Tags: отладка, macos, linux

Имеется яблочная программа(64bit), нужно понять принцип работы и написать аналогичную. Установленного мака нет, в идеале было бы сделать все это на линуксе(i686), в крайнем случае на виртуалке/эмуляторе мака. Посоветуйте отладчик, который осуществит задуманное.

Answer (score 1):

[Вот тебе инструкция по установки Mac OS под VMware](http://www.sysprobs.com/easily-run-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-retail-on-pc-with-vmware-image)

Как поставить VMware на линукс на сайте vmware посмотри

Comment: с каких пор вмварь отладчик? я бы сам справился с установкой мака, я не знаю чем дебагать.

Comment: @Templar  
> я не знаю чем дебагать  
  
Проще будет установить OS X в виртуальную машину, как уже сказал @dolpa, и воспользоваться GDB + IDA (вместо IDA можно взять Hopper Disassembler; он, помимо всего прочего, ещё и является фронтэндом для GDB).  
А вообще, проблема только в запуске программы на линуксе, потому как и IDA и Hopper — то есть средства статического анализа — кроссплатформенны.